# dijit.form.select dropdown is very slow

Tags: select, dojo

Loading 3000 values into **dijit.form.select** control takes longer time. browser gets hanged even for 500 values. How to over come this problem?

Any assistance would be really appreciated.

Thanks,
Karthihck k.

Comment: Which Dojo version? Which browser? How are you filling the select? How are you generating the select?

Answer (score 1):

Loading 3,000 of *anything* into a web page is always going to be slow.

Although there are twisted ways to overcome this limitation, it may not be worth it for your user is definitely *not* going to like scrolling through 3,000 items to pick one!

I'd suggest you break this drop-down list into two (or three) levels, and have no more than 20-30 choices each.  In one of my own projects with thousands of list items, I had to go with *four* levels, otherwise performance gets abysmal.

If you only have one long list to work with, consider breaking it down by the starting letter into 26 groups, like a phone list.  At least you'll have only 100-200 in each group.

Now, if you **really really** want to load such a long list, consider not using `dijit.form.Select` as it is just a simple wrapper for the `<select>` tag.  You're essentially inserting one `<option>` tag at a time, killing performance.  You have two choices:

1. Create the list of `<option>` tags yourself off-line, then insert into the `<select>` element in one go.
2. Consider `dijit.form.FilteringSelect` instead.

Now, I **definitely don't** endorse doing the above.  You've been warned!

Comment: IBM Rational ClearQuest uses a very weird paginated select widget. It's not very nice :(